# Using .plot.line plot y = x + 6 with x values of your choosing. create labels for the x & y axis and a graph title

Tags: python

Using .plot.line plot y = x + 6 with x values of your choosing. create labels for the x & y axis and a graph title.

```
x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,8}
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.title('My first graph!')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You seem to have missed defining the `y` values in your code snippet.
Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
y = [xi + 6 for xi in x]
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x - axis')
plt.ylabel('y - axis')
plt.title('My first graph!')
plt.show()
```

**Output Graph:**

[image: output graph]

If you are required to use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.line`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8]
y = [xi + 6 for xi in x]
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
ax = df.plot.line(x='x', y='y')
ax.set_xlabel('x - axis')
ax.set_ylabel('y - axis')
ax.set_title('My first graph!')
plt.show()
```

**Output Graph:**

[image: output graph 2]